# In MS Edge, placeholder text doesn't disappear after entering text in input type="number"

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, html-input

To see the issue try this Snippet:

```html
<div>
    <span>A number input:</span>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter some TEXT">
</div>
<div>
    <span>A text input:</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">
</div>
```

The behavior of `input type="number"` in:

- **Chrome**: Unable to input text. When numbers are input, placeholder text disappears as expected.
- **Internet Explorer**: Able to input text, but when text or numbers are input, placeholder text disappears as expected.
- **Edge**: Able to input text, and when text is input, placeholder text *does not disappear!*

What?! Is this really just a crazy bug in Edge? If so, I hope that the right people are aware of this bug, but I couldn't find any other people complaining of it.

Any ideas on the best way to compensate for this problem?

Comment: Interestingly, I can type `e` into the number field in Chrome. Huh. Not `i` though!

Comment: Maybe to allow for scientific notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always manually filter out letters by watching the `keypress` event.  Here's some JQuery code that will only allow you to type "0123456789" into a number textbox:

```
$("input[type='number']").keypress(function(event){
    // If this key is not a number...
    if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Here's your JSFiddle forked to include this code: https://jsfiddle.net/o263wmnh/

Comment: Ugh, yeah. Before I did that, I'd just dispense with the type="number" altogether, and just let my frameworks handle the client-side validation.